# Is there any semantic difference between due/due to and because/because of?

Tags: prepositions

So far, the question about the difference between the terms from the title was asked several times here and on ELU but I'm not asking about the **grammatical difference** my question is about semantics.

Please let me make it clearer:

In my language, there's a clear distinction between the terms so as to that they cannot semantically be used interchangeable as **due to** carries a positive connotation whereas **because of** carries a negative one. **Due to** is closer to **owing to** or **thanks to**. This said, in my language, you cannot say:

> I feel unhappy **due to/owing to** the fact that I broke my leg.

It is as if I were to say:

> I feel unhappy **thanks to** the fact that I broke my leg.

It is correct to say:

> I feel unhappy **because** I broke my leg.

Inverse, you cannot say:

> I'm glad **because** you came.

So you would correctly say:

> I'm glad **due/owing/thanks** to your coming.

Despite all the above, in my language, many well educated people journalists, TV show people, etc. make this mistake when using those terms. It is actually a common mistake.

I didn't see hitherto such a distinction in English which is why I wonder if there is one or, like in my language, people don't care too much about their use.

Comment: This is not really your answer, but your question invited me to reflect on the question: Are human thoughts universal? You may (or may not) find [my reflection](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22285075#22285075) interesting. (Warning: read it at your own risk. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT., I found it quite interesting.:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no semantic distinction comparable to that in your language between *due to*, *owing to*, *thanks to*, *because of*. Any of them may be employed to signify the cause of both happy and unpleasant events.

> 2014 was our best year ever, due to the outstanding efforts of the marketing department.
> 2014 was our best year ever, thanks to the outstanding efforts of the marketing department.
> 2014 was our best year ever, owing to the outstanding efforts of the marketing department.
> 2014 was our best year ever, because of the outstanding efforts of the marketing department.
>
> 2014 was a complete disaster, due to the rank incompetence of the marketing department.
> 2014 was a complete disaster, thanks to the rank incompetence of the marketing department.
> 2014 was a complete disaster, owing to the rank incompetence of the marketing department.
> 2014 was a complete disaster, because of the rank incompetence of the marketing department.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that "thanks to" is odd man out because it's the only one that I think really needs the comma before it.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Mmmm ... I think omitting the comma changes the sense with all of them: it makes the preposition phrase a restrictive modifier on the preceding nominal rather than a sentential modifier. "We've had a lot of great years/disasters, but the others were attributable to good/bad weather; 2014 was a great year/disaster attributable to the marketing department's efforts."

Comment: Much obliged @StoneyB!:-) +1

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning. As "due to" is ultimately French/Latin it is not very frequent in normal spoken language. In written language it is a slightly elevated variant of "because of". As the latter preposition is used very frequently there are variants.